# Magento Go SOAP API V2 customer create does not pass some optional fields

Tags: php, api, magento, soap

I'm using Magento Go's SOAP API V2 to created customers. When using customerCustomerCreate,  the values firstname, lastname, email and password all get passed in successfully, but I can't seem to set the dob.  I thought maybe it was a date formatting issue, so I tried middlename, which doesn't get set either.  I don't get any error response from the API, so I don't think my values are invalid.  I'm just not seeing them in the record that is created.  Has anyone experienced this?

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://...');

$session = $client->login('api_user', 'api_pass');
$result = $client->customerCustomerCreate($session, array(
    'email' => 'example@email.com', 
    'firstname' => 'First', 
    'lastname' => 'Last',
    'middlename' => 'Middle', 
    'gender' => 1,
    'password' => 'password', 
    'website_id' => 1, 
    'store_id' => 1, 
    'group_id' => 1,
));

$result = $client->customerCustomerInfo($session, $result);

var_dump($result);
```

The result, where middlename and gender is missing:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (11) {
    ["customer_id"]=> int(53) 
    ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2012-10-19 15:32:24" 
    ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2012-10-19 15:32:24" 
    ["store_id"]=> int(1) 
    ["website_id"]=> int(1) 
    ["created_in"]=> string(7) "English" 
    ["email"]=> string(17) "example@email.com" 
    ["firstname"]=> string(5) "First" 
    ["lastname"]=> string(4) "Last" 
    ["group_id"]=> int(1) 
    ["password_hash"]=> string(67) "(password hash)" 
}
```

Comment: Sounds more like a question for Magento Go support than stack overflow.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Could you sh your api call code here?

Answer (score 1):

You can Use SOAP V1 API and pass value of date of birth in customer data array With key and value.It will store Date of birth.